# How to read CSV file with delimiter different than comma?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe with text columns. It seems that Pyspark dataframe will truncate the content of the text columns if it contains ','.

This is how I am saving the file.

```py
read_file = spark.read.csv('C://data/myfile.csv', header = True, inferSchema = True)

# Do some processing then save file as csv
read_file = read_file.select(read_file.text_col.cast(StringType())
read_file.coalesce(1).write.csv('text.csv', mode = 'overwrite', header = True)

Sample of text:

Bot[10/26/2019 09:21:44]: Hi there, welcome to XXX. I will be your virtual assistant today.

After saving it will output this:
>>> Bot[10/26/2019 09:21:44]: Hi there
```

I have tried converting the column into StringType but it is still truncating the column if it containts a ','.

Comment: Also, have you tried using `quoteAll` argument? [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=save#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv)

Comment: @samkartI just tried quoteAll = True, and the results is the same. Still truncates after ','. Currently, as a workaround I had to remove all ',' from the original file.

Comment: Try saving the file as a `tsv` once, and see if the results are same? I think it's because of the comma in *Hi there, welcome to XXX* that you're getting the problem.

Comment: try with text file as well. [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=save#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.text) `read_file.write.text(path)`

Comment: use `sep=None` parameter and try. tweak the value of seperator and see the results. try with the value '~' or '\' anc check your results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `.option("delimiter", "|")` with whatever delimiter (separator) input datasets use.

---

> I have PySpark dataframe with text columns.

That would suggest to use `text()` (not `csv()`) method instead.

> It seems that Pyspark dataframe will truncate the content of the text columns if it contains ','.

It is `csv()` method (the CSV data source actually) while loading a dataset per the default configuration that assumes `,` (comma) as the separator. It does not truncate, but parses lines according to the separator.

Using `delimiter` (or `sep`) option should "fix" it.